# Are all languages determined in exponential time NP languages?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, turing-machines, np

According to the theorem, if $L \in NP$, then $L$ can be determined by a deterministic Turing machine in exponential time.

So, are all languages determined in exponential time NP languages?

Comment: Is EXPTIME = NP? who knows ...

Comment: The answer to this question can be found on the Wikipedia article on [EXPTIME](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME).